# HttpURLConnection timeout not working by setting the system properties

Tags: java, network-programming, timeout, httpurlconnection

I want my application to timeout in some specific seconds, but it keeps on trying to contact the specified URL until it gets a response. Below is the code I am using.

```
System.getProperties().setProperty("sun.net.client.defaultConnectTimeout", timeOut);

System.getProperties().setProperty("sun.net.client.defaultReadTimeout", timeOut); 

URL url = new URL(targetURL);

HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
```

but if I set following property

```
connection.setConnectTimeout(Integer.parseInt(timeout));
```

then it gets timed out in desired time without waiting for server's response.

So, why doesn't it get timed out by using just the system properties?

**Edit**: Does it have anything to do with this [behavior/bug](http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=6245589)? Or is there any relation with Java version, because the same code used to work in Java 1.4 but now I am using Java 1.7.

Comment: @brso05 Can you suggest something?

Answer (score 4):

A standard approach to object-oriented design is *defensive copying.*  This means that methods return copies of their data, rather than returning the actual internal object itself, so other code cannot attempt to perform harmful actions without going through the API from which it obtained the object, so the changes can be checked for validity.

`System.getProperties()` returns a Properties object which is a *copy* of the internal system properties.  Use [System.setProperty](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#setProperty-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) instead.

Comment: You are correct about the "defensive copying" thing but it's not working with the changes you suggested though.

Comment: What is the actual value of `timeOut`?

Comment: 40000 milliseconds

Comment: Are you certain the *string* value of `timeOut` is `"40000"`?  No spaces, no punctuation?

Comment: I am quite sure, because it is working fine with 'connection.setConnectTimeout(Integer.parseInt(timeout));'